# whats the best way to create a menu screen with a zoomable image background

Tags: android, layout

I need to create a screen with either buttons or hotspots that I plan to use as menu items to take me to another part of the app. The image is a floor plan and I want to click names or buttons or graphics to use as navigation.

I'm at the early stages and I'm just looking for a direction to focus on. Do I need to do complicated calculations based on the image location and the click location or can I fix buttons to a view and make it zoomable.

I think maybe I should add that I want the menu to start off full screen but the users to be able to pinch, zoom and drag the menu screen just to make it easier for users to see icons and text

Thanks

I have been looking for possible solutions and have read about using a view under my image with different colours where I want to listen for clicks, and the clicks would return colours. I think this might be the way to go, an image below with different coloured sections would resize the same as the image above so my clickable areas would always be in the correct position. If anyone can tell me how to achieve this or ideally point me to a tutorial that would be excellent.

Comment: what if you had an overlay on the image that after you zoomed/clicked on it it would show for 2 seconds and then disappear. Kinda like how facebook does theres but with the image taking the full screen size if necessary and it should show the HUD upon first load of the viewer. Also make the HUD semi-transparent.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but what I am trying to create is a floor plan of a large building with a link to the rooms, when the image is first shown it will be zoomed out to show the complete floor plan but the downside of that will be detail and text will be difficult to read so what I need to do is allow users to zoom into areas of interest by zooming in and sweeping the image across as well as pinching to zoom out. I liked the idea of the overlayed invisible view because that seems to easily solve any issues caused by resizing or distortion. I'm tied to this as there is also an apple app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well... I'd suggest doing a "hot zone" view detector on top of a surface view that detects taps, but if this is a one-off then you can easily carve up the image in photoshop and just draw a bunch of ImageViews, laid out precisely next to each other and serving as individual buttons. You can animate their layout_width/height when clicked, which would automatically shove the other ones aside to produce the effect of zooming in on the zone you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks Dr Dredel a hot zone on top of a surface view sounds good to me can you give me an idea of where to look to implement that. Thanks

Comment: sure... look at this example, for instance: http://marakana.com/tutorials/android/2d-graphics-example.html Don't worry about the drawing bits... just notice how you detect the coordinates of the user's taps. You can sit this custom View on top of your image view and either hard code the coords to be matched against, or save them in an XML and read that in at run time. If your shapes are odd polygons it becomes a little trickier to detect if their tap is inside that shape. There's probably some collision detection stuff you can find if you look around.